# Refusing to install semantic-ui as a dependency of itself

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-ui, npm-install

Why npm install of semantic ui producing error,

Refusing to install semantic-ui as a dependency of itself

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: Can you list the exact steps (commands) used to reproduce this error?

Comment: I followed the steps in the semantics ui docs itself. http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html#using-build-tools using npm.